# The "https://flex.symfony.com/aliases.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Hote inconnu

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I joined a symfony project and install all the packages via composer, and succeed to connect to my local mysql via wamp and migrate the DB but any time I try to add a package like :

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
```

I keep getting this error :

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://flex.symfony.com/aliases.json" file could not be downloaded: 
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H�te inconnu.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H�te inconnu.
```

I am not necessarily a symfony guy, So any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the composer.json :

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.5",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "automattic/woocommerce": "^3.0",
    "babdev/pagerfanta-bundle": "^2.8",
    "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.10.1",
    "csa/guzzle-bundle": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.8",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^3.0",
    "gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle": "^0.12.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^3.7",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.10",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^4.1",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.1",
    "paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "1.0.1",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.76",
    "symfony/asset": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.19",
    "symfony/form": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/intl": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/mime": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/notifier": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/process": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/property-access": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/property-info": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/string": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/translation": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.2",
    "symfony/validator": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "5.2.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "5.2.*",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
    "twig/twig": "^2.0",
    "willdurand/hateoas-bundle": "^2.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.2",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^5.2",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.2",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.2",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.2",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.2",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.2"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "symfony/flex": true
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "5.2.*"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like that URL simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Sure but why do am I even redirected there ?

Comment: We don't know - we don't know what project or packages you've used or anything about what it does.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post with more details

Comment: At a guess, symfony/flex might be the culprit? Probably worth raising a ticket with symfony about this, not sure what we could do about it here.

Comment: All my colleagues are apparently able to require that package perfectly fine

Comment: If not, please share which version of `symfony/flex` you are using

Comment: https://symfony.com/blog/upgrade-flex-on-your-symfony-projects could also help

Comment: Sadly it require me to update to composer 2 and my tema is still working on the v1 of composer. And Symfony flex is version 1.19

Comment: What pins you to composer 1?